# APEX_ITEM Select list ...All item are there but invisible

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Hi and sorry for the unusual title but it's actually what I am facing right now with my app

I created this page that uses apex_item and apex collections to display and store

A list of lap test names and prices.

Everything was just fine up until the upgrade to 19,2 from 19.0, when this upgrade

Was done the problems started, first the UI and the styling went crazy -I have a modified

Theme to support RTL- so long story short I restored my APP and theme only to notice that

The page does not display the select lit correctly

The code I used is as simple as follows:

SELECT LEVEL AS item_no,
         APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(1,'Test','SELECT DISTINCT LAP_TEST_ENG_NAME FROM LAP_TESTS', 'class="zz"') AS "Test"
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_NUMBER (:P41_HOW_MANY)

As you can see the items in the list are there an can be selected and the rest of the processing run normally

But it can not be seen.

I tried to customize the styling of the list using this class 'zz' and the background was changed

to black the foreground was only changed in the extra value -written in Arabic here-

But every item in the list is still invisible

[image]

What am I missing?

All other select list items that are not created by APEX_ITEM are working normally

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Thanks and waiting for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

OK I Think I fixed it ...(I hope!)

The SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY and according to the official documentation is supposed to

Use the column name as both display value and return value if only one column is specified in the select clause of this query here is the quote from the documentation:

"

Note that this is used only by the SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY function.

Also note, if only one column is specified in the select clause of this query, the value for this column is used for both display and return purposes."

but for some reason and only after the 19.2 update this behavior has changed and the function now needs to have both  display and return value

Or it will use the single column as return value and show an empty line as the display value!

This is why I was getting no errors and the return values where returned as usual even though there were nothing seen in the select list

So all I had to do was to change my query to have a second column as a display value and now all looks fine

APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(1,'Test','SELECT LAP_TEST_ENG_NAME a, LAP_TEST_ENG_NAME b FROM LAP_TESTS', 'class="zz"') AS "Test"

```
enter code here
```